# scaling assets without changing sprite position

Tags: c++, mobile, cocos2d-x

I am porting a cocos2d-iphone 2.0 game to cocos2d-x. In the old code, I disabled retina, and cocos2d-iphone 2.0 scaled assets for me. I know this is not the way to go, but it worked as a temp workaround.

I am trying to port the game to cocos2d-x 3.x (3.7.1). Overall, the process is not too rocky.

I do want however to temporary be able to use my old pre-retina assets, until the functionality is ready. Eventually, I will receive assets for retina and iPhone 6 etc.

What can I do now? I tried to calculate the scale then call:

```
director->setContentScaleFactor(ratio);
```

However, while this correctly scales images, my sprite's position is also scaled. I don't want this. Is there a way to tell cocos2d-x to scale bitmaps? I use tiles for my game.

Please advise if you have experience with this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the right/easiest way to deal with this is still to scale the tile map resources. there are even tools to assist with the process. one is WBTMXTool and there are others.
Apparently, there is no trick.